# Journale of RADIUS server

Tags: server, authentication, nas, client, radius

i want to see the access(times ,actions) of client to the RADIUS server, 
what's the command to view the the file log of RADIUS server plz

Answer (score 2):

In *buntu:
`tail -f /var/log/freeradius/radius.log`

Because the log contains information that should be kept secure, it is by default only readable by root.

You can also start the server in debug mode to get a lot more detail.

`# freeradius -X`

Before doing this, check to see if freeradius is already running (e.g. `ps ax | fgrep freeradius`). If it is running, stop it with `service freeradius stop`.

In debug mode with the -X switch, freeradius remains attached to the terminal so it can output detailed information via STDOUT on the terminal screen.

For extended detailed logging, you could `nohup freeradius -X >/tmp/radius.log &`.

Even more detailed logging is available with the `-x` and `-xx` switches.